# How to specify the scope for a key and related keyref in XML schema?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

This is my case: I got (inside a root element) many `nffg` subelements, each one made of `nodes` and `links` element (minOccurs and maxOccurs equal to 1 for both). `nodes` is a sequence of `node` elements (+), each one containing a `nodeName` element and I want it to be the key. `links` is a sequence of `link` (*), each one containing `sourceNode` and `destNode` elements.

I've tried many XPath possibilities, but I can't reach what I want. I'm trying to make `nodeName` as key and `sourceNode` and `destNode` referring to one of those `nodeName`, but only for `node` in the same `nffg`.

XML example:

```
    <nffg nffgName="nffg1" deployTime="1999-11-12T21:00:12">
        <nodes>
            <node functionalType="func1">
                <nodeName>node1</nodeName>
            </node>
            <node functionalType="func2">
                <nodeName>node3</nodeName>
            </node>
            <node functionalType="func2">
                <nodeName>node4</nodeName>
            </node>
        </nodes>
        <links>
            <link>
                <sourceNode>node1</sourceNode>
                <destNode>node2</destNode>
            </link>
        </links>
    </nffg>
    <nffg nffgName="nffg2" deployTime="1999-11-12T22:00:12">
        <nodes>
            <node functionalType="func2">
                <nodeName>node2</nodeName>
            </node>
        </nodes>
        <links>
            <link>
                <sourceNode>node1</sourceNode>
                <destNode>node2</destNode>
            </link>
        </links>
    </nffg>
```

Fragment of XML schema (these constraints are defined inside the root element):

```
        <xsd:key name="nodeNameKey">
            <xsd:selector xpath="nffg/nodes/node"></xsd:selector>
            <xsd:field xpath="nodeName"></xsd:field>
        </xsd:key>
        <xsd:keyref name="linkSourceNode" refer="nodeNameKey">
            <xsd:selector xpath="nffg/links/link"></xsd:selector>
            <xsd:field xpath="sourceNode"></xsd:field>
        </xsd:keyref>
        <xsd:keyref name="linkDestNode" refer="nodeNameKey">
            <xsd:selector xpath="nffg/links/link"></xsd:selector>
            <xsd:field xpath="destNode"></xsd:field>
        </xsd:keyref>
```

At the moment, this is valid with respect to my xsd, but I would like to make this not valid because, as you can notice, there is a `link` in nffg1  using as destNode `node2`, which is defined in nffg2 (so, I would like to create a nffg-scope for `link`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, let's rule out the possibilities of defining the key and keyref at different levels. That's allowed, but it's mind-boggling and I've never seen a need for it (or formed a useful mental picture of how it works).

If we rule out that possibility, then there are two things you want to say:

(1) Within an X, every Y has a unique value for Z

(2) Within an X, every R has a value for S that corresponds to one of the values of Z that is present within the same X.

To achieve (1) you define a key named N within the element declaration for X, with selector being a path that selects Y from X, and field being a path that selects Z from Y.

To achieve (2) you define a keyref within the element declaration for X,
that names N as its target key, with selector being a path that selects R from X, and field being a path that selects S from R.

So in your case:

Within the element declaration for `nffg`, define

```
key name="N"
    selector = nodes/node
    field = nodeName

keyRef refer="N"    
    selector = links/link
    field = sourceNode

keyRef refer="N"    
    selector = links/link
    field = destNode
```

The critical thing here in terms of your headline question is that if you want things to be unique within an `nffg`, you define the key and keyref constraints within the element declaration for `nffg`.